# Optimize sum of series with genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

As I am new to optimization toolbox in MATLAB I am struggling with the right code on how to optimize my objective function. At the beginning I have the following data:

```
a = [3 3 1 1];
c = [2 5 5 10];
```

My objective function along with the equality and inequality constraints are:

```
F=∑(k=1..4){[0.2.*a(k)]+[0.16.*x_1(k)]+[b(k).*x_2 (k)]}
```

The objective function `F` is a sum of series from `k = 1..4`

Equality Constraints:

```
a(k)+x_1 (k)+x_2 (k)=c(k)  AND  d(k)=x_1 (k)+d(k-1)
```

Inequality Constraints

```
x_1 (k)≤d(k)≤10
```

The variables that optimize the above function are `x1(k)` and `x2(k)`. Is there a method how can I do that?

Image of the equations:
[image]

Comment: If `b(k)` is not constrained, your problem is unbounded (`b(k) = -oo`).

Comment: b(k) is a given constant that varies from 0 to 1. It's not calculated by the optimization tool. Let's say that the b(k) is 0.19 always.

Comment: If `b(k)` is fixed, you have a linear program so you can use http://fr.mathworks.com/discovery/linear-programming.html

Comment: And `d(0)` is also fixed?

Comment: yes d(0) is fixed and given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your constraints are linear, you can use [linear programming](http://fr.mathworks.com/discovery/linear-programming.html):

```
clear all;

n_k = 4; % number of k
n_v = 3; % number of variables

a = [3 3 1 1];
b = [0.19 0.19 0.19 0.19];
c = [2 5 5 10];

d0 = 0;

% Objective x1 x2 d
f = zeros(1, n_k * n_v);
f(1:n_v:end) = 0.16; % x1 coefficient
f(2:n_v:end) = b; % x2 coefficient (b(k))

% Equality 1
eq1 = [1 1 0]; % x1 + x2 + 0 * d = c(k) - a(k)
Aeq = zeros(2 * n_k, n_v * n_k);
for i = 1:1:n_k
    Aeq(i, :) = cat(2, eq1, zeros(1, n_k * n_v - length(eq1)));
    eq1 = cat(2, zeros(1, n_v), eq1);
end
eq2 = [1 1 0 -1]; % d(k-1) + x1(k) + 0 * x2(k) - d(k) = 0
Aeq(n_k + 1, :) = [1 0 -1 0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0  0];
Aeq(n_k + 2, :) = [0 0  1 1 0 -1 0 0  0 0 0  0];
Aeq(n_k + 3, :) = [0 0  0 0 0  1 1 0 -1 0 0  0];
Aeq(n_k + 4, :) = [0 0  0 0 0  0 0 0  1 1 0 -1];
beq = zeros(1, 8);
beq(1:n_k) = c - a;
beq(5) = -d0;

% Inequality
le1 = [1 0 -1];
A = zeros(n_k, n_v * n_k);
for i = 1:1:n_k
    A(i, :) = cat(2, le1, zeros(1, n_k * n_v - length(le1)));
    le1 = cat(2, zeros(1, n_v), le1);
end
b = zeros(1, 4);

ub = inf(1, n_k * n_v);
ub(3:n_v:end) = 10;
lb = -inf(1, n_k * n_v);
```

And to solve:

```
X = linprog(f, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
```

Output:

```
>> reshape(X, 3, 4)

ans =

    5.8261    1.1680   -4.1562    7.1621
   -6.8261    0.8320    8.1562    1.8379
    5.8261    6.9941    2.8379   10.0000
```

You can check:

```
>> [X(1:3:end), X(2:3:end), transpose(a), 
    X(1:3:end) + X(2:3:end) + transpose(a), transpose(c)]

ans =

    5.8261   -6.8261    3.0000    2.0000    2.0000
    1.1680    0.8320    3.0000    5.0000    5.0000
   -4.1562    8.1562    1.0000    5.0000    5.0000
    7.1621    1.8379    1.0000   10.0000   10.0000

>> [X(3:3:end), X(1:3:end), X(3:3:end) - X(1:3:end), [0; X(3:3:11)]]

ans =

    5.8261    5.8261   -0.0000         0
    6.9941    1.1680    5.8261    5.8261
    2.8379   -4.1562    6.9941    6.9941
   10.0000    7.1621    2.8379    2.8379

>> [X(1:3:end), X(3:3:end)]

ans =

    5.8261    5.8261
    1.1680    6.9941
   -4.1562    2.8379
    7.1621   10.0000
```

---

*Old answer (before comment)*

```
% Objective a c d x1 x2
f = [.2 0 0 .16 .19];
f = repmat(f, 1, 4);

% Equality 1
eq1 = [1 -1 0 1 1]; % a c d x1 x1
eq2 = [1 0 0 0 0 -1 1 0]; % d(k-1) x1(k-1) x2(k-1) a(k) c(k) d(k) x1(k) x2(k)
Aeq = [cat(2, eq1, zeros(1, 15));
     cat(2, zeros(1, 5), eq1, zeros(1, 10));
     cat(2, zeros(1, 10), eq1, zeros(1, 5));
     cat(2, zeros(1, 15), eq1);
     cat(2, zeros(1, 2), eq2, zeros(1, 10));
     cat(2, zeros(1, 7), eq2, zeros(1, 5));
     cat(2, zeros(1, 12), eq2)];
beq = zeros(1, 7);
% Inequality
le1 = [0 0 -1 1 0];
A   = [cat(2, le1, zeros(1, 15));
       cat(2, zeros(1, 5), le1, zeros(1, 10));
       cat(2, zeros(1, 10), le1, zeros(1, 5));
       cat(2, zeros(1, 15), le1)];
b = zeros(1, 4);
ub = [inf inf 10 inf inf];
ub = repmat(ub, 1, 4);
lb = ones(1, 5) * (-inf);
lb = repmat(lb, 1, 4);

ub(3) = d0;
lb(3) = d0;
```

And to solve:

```
linprog(f, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub)
```

Note that there are probably some information missing in your original post since it looks like this problem is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Holt. But, where does the algorithm read for a = [3 3 1 1] and c = [2 2 5 10]? 

By the way you are right about the constraints and the constraints are:

-10<=d(k)<=10, 
x1(k)<=d(k), 
-3<=x2(k)<=10,

Comment: once again I really appriciate your support. How the equality constraint is met here? for example a(1) + x1(1) + x2(1) = c(1) - i.e. 3 + 10 - 10  =! 2. Sorry for any inconvience but as I said at the beginning I am new here

Comment: @George Sorry, I forgot to replace the `b` with `c(k) - a(k)` (`beq(1:n_k) = c - a;`), see my edit.

Comment: is function f optimized for each k or for all k's as a sum of series? For k = 4 I need only one value of f which is the global minimum

Comment: @George f is optimized for the sum.

Comment: what if I want to add one more constraint so d(0) >= x1(1)?

Comment: I think that in your answer the lower bound for x2 is not considered - -3<=x2(k)<=10.

Comment: @George You did not specify that lower bound in the original post so I could not guess it. To modify lower and upper bound on your variables, you simplify have to modify the `ub` (upper bounds) and `lb` (lower bounds) vector, where `ub(1)` is `x1(1)`, `ub(2)` is `x2(1)`, `ub(3)` is `d(1)`, `ub(4)` is `x1(2)` and so on...